# pytorch: implementing logistic regression: input dimension of torch.nn.Linear is input.flatten(start_dim=1)

Tags: machine-learning, python, logistic-regression, pytorch

I tried to implement a logistic regression class using pytorch. The following implementation worked.

```
class LR(torch.nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, input_dim, output_dim):
        """ Initializes internal Module state. """
        super(LR, self).__init__()
        self.input_dim = input_dim
        self.output_dim = output_dim
        self.linear = torch.nn.Linear(input_dim, output_dim)
         

    def forward(self, x):
        x = x.flatten(start_dim=1) 
        x = self.linear(x)
        outputs = x
        
        return outputs
```

I expected it to work with `x = x.view(-1, self.input_dim)` instead of `x = x.flatten(start_dim=1)`. I thought `torch.nn.Linear(input_dim, output_dim)` only accepts inputs of shape `(any shape, input_dim)`. `x = x.flatten(start_dim=1)` reshapes to (batch_size, flattened_size) with flattened_size being the product of all dimensions of x starting from dimension 1. how would this not raise an error?